# Detect if app is running on localhost when there are no requests

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a worker class in my web app and I'd like to know if the code is running on my laptop's dev server or on the production server. NOTE: **there is no request processing when the code is running** so `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal` will not work.

How can I detect where the code is running?

Comment: How is the product deployed to the production server?

Comment: Generally the only *difference* between environments should be the configuration.  Maybe a flag in the `Web.config`?  What's the context of this need, what problem is being addressed?

Comment: You could use System.Environment.MachineName.

Comment: @David: I have client files that are generated by the app and there's a worker that checks to see if all the client files needed are there and if not generate them. But when I'm running locally and debugging the app, I don't want this code to run

Comment: I agree with David about using web.config for differentiating instead of other options. What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to run a background thread in the web app?

Comment: What do you mean by a "worker"? Did you spin up a separate thread in your web app?

Comment: @mason: every X minutes, there's a Task that launches the worker.

Comment: And how did you implement this "every X minutes" logic? In a separate thread?

Comment: Again... how is the product deployed to the production server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A debug flag could be one option:

```
#if (!DEBUG)
    // code that shouldn't run while debugging
#endif
```

I often personally find those a little unintuitive, though can't really quantify why in any objective sense.  Though if it's possible that you'd ever run the app in Release (perhaps as a kind of smoke test) without wanting that code to run, that could be an issue.

Going with the general notion that the only difference between environments should be the configuration (that is, after all, what `Web.config` is for) then you can manually achieve the same result with a config flag.  Something as simple as:

```
<add key="runBackgroundWorker" value="true" />
```

And in the code you would set some flag based on that (could be a direct reference to the configuration, could be a statically loaded config object, however you normally handle your configs) and use basically the same condition as above:

```
// for example...
var runBackgroundWorker = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["runBackgroundWorker"]);
// though perhaps put in more error checking, etc.

// later...
if (runBackgroundWorker)
{
    // code that shouldn't run while debugging
}
```

This gives you the added flexibility of turning that feature on and off in any environment, regardless of Debug or Release builds.  (QA, UAT, demo environment, etc.)

Comment: ok, going with the config flag, didn't know about it so thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your local server is not changing, nor is the production server you could run a compare against `Environment.MachineName` in the worker class.

Something like:

```
    var devServer = "myMachineName";
    var currentServer = Environment.MachineName;

    if(devServer == currentServer)
    {
       /// local dev machine
    }
```

[Environment.MachineName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename(v=vs.110).aspx)